# Why do my upgraded Grails projects have red exclamation marks?

Tags: eclipse, grails

I've upgraded my Grails and on every project ( already created or new ) I have red exclamation mark. Projects are working fine.
I tried to fix it with Groovy-->Fix Compiler Mismatch Problem, with refresh dependence and Project-->Clean but without avail.
I thought that it could be problem with build path but I don't know how to fix it, so if anyone could help...

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT *(I've fixed it for you on this occasion; also note that questions should be **questions**...)*

Comment: No probl, I'm new in all this,and every help is welcome ;)

Comment: I assume you use Eclipse, but you should provide more details - version number, is it STS, GGTS?

Comment: You haven't said what the error messages are.  Just saying "red exclamation marks" isn't enough to get good answers.

Comment: I don't have any error message, just that "red exclamation mark" next to the name of project. I'm using Grails 2.2.4

Comment: Open the problems view and the error log, copy and paste what they say. Most likely you have build issues, such as a path to a required lib being wrong. 

Also, right click on the project and select properties. You will probably find the issue there.

Comment: in error log--> Description Resource Path Location Type
Groovy: compiler mismatch Project level is: 2.0 Workspace level is 2.1
Groovy compiler level expected by the project does not match workspace compiler level. 
Groovy compiler mismatch problem

Comment: That describes the problem.  Grails 2.2.4 uses Groovy 2.0.8.  You can either configure the IDE to ignore that issue in preferences under Groovy->Compiler or you can install the 2.0 compiler support for greclipse and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this loads of times doing this sort of stuff, the first thing to do is do a grails command wizard and clean

```
or grails clean
```

The try doing a

> grails refresh dependencies

If you have actually upgraded grails over all and just copied your application folder into the new ggts (grails install) then a few things you need to do:

Create a new project under your new grails/ggts -  take a look at applications.properties:

1. edit current applications.properties :

   app.grails.version=2.3.7

Ensure the application version matches what you have in your newly created app under upgrade..

Then open grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy for the new project under new upgrade and check closely the configuration. Infact copy entire BuildConfig.groovy over to your existing project and add any additional plugins you have in your project to the new BuildConfig.groovy

Then retry `grails clean grails refresh depenedencies`

This should fix issues.

Answer (score 0):

Its most probably due to missing link to grails plugin. You can always delete those red exclamation marks by opening "Problem" view (GGTS -> Windows > Show View -> Others -> General -> Problems) and delete all errors if don't want to see them.

This is doable if you are not running your grails server from GGTS.

-SA